# Kannel receiving and processing long SMS

Tags: sms-gateway, kannel

Kannel 1.4.3

I need to receive "long" sms (length > 160 symbols) by Kannel. If sms length less than 160 - all is ok. But if it is long sms kannel splits sms to 2 or more sms and send not like one concatened sms but 2 or more different messages.

I tried to use

```
sms-combine-concatenated-mo = true
```

in kannel.conf core section but it did not help.

Here is my sms-service config:

```
# SMS Gateway Reciever
group = sms-service
keyword = default
omit-empty = true
post-url = "http://localhost:22222/recievesms?from=%p&time=%t&smsc=%i&coding=%c&service=%n&charset=%C"
concatenation = true
```

Can anybody suggest how to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem was resolved by installing new version (daily snapshot) of Kannel.